# Controller tests and stubbing filters/actions. What's the guideline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, rspec

Is stubbing filters/actions in controller specs considered as a good practise?

Let's say I have filter `authorize!` on almost every controller. Can I just stub it in all controller specs or I should have shared examples for testing each action if it has filter/action behaviour?

Things are getting messy when there are dozen of filters/actions on controllers (also inherited...)

Comment: Can you post some specs as examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO you should only stub when you need to. Some good reasons are:

- The test depends on some well-documented external API that you don't control
- The action/method to be stubbed is very slow and you have another test that covers it (i.e. it is a *dependency* of the test, not the subject of the test
- You are building a new feature and stubbing code that does not yet exist, and you intend to remove the stub when the code is implemented

"Messiness" is not a good reason. RSpec provides a plethora of tools for cleaning up test code and making it more readable. Spend some time improving the tests and you may find that the desire for stubbing things out is reduced.